# How do I edit my staged file?

Tags: git

I used patch mode to add a file.  It took a good while to add only the changes I wanted in this commit.  But then I realized I had made a mistake.  There was one block of code I don't want in this commit.

Is there a way I can edit the staged change set without changing my working directory and not repeating the long process of `git add -up somefile`?

Answer (score 45, accepted):

Yes, just use `git reset -p` to selectively unstage patches.

Comment: This is what I wanted; thank you.  However, when make the edit I need the patch fails.

Comment: @Gn13l: Then I suggest the following: `s`plit the affected hunk into the smallest units, unstage the hunk containing the edit you want to make, and `git add -p` with `e`dit to edit in exactly the hunk you want.

Comment: I tried something very similar.  I un-staged the hunk, then went back and did `add -p` to the file.  It didn't compare to what I had already added.  It took me through the entire patch process again.

Comment: Does `git diff --cached` show you the changes you've already staged? If not you may have accidentally unstaged everything.

Comment: It's worth noting that `git reset -p` works in the opposite way that `git add -p` does.  Hitting `y` during an `add` will move the hunk into the staged area.  Conversely, hitting `y` during `reset` will remove it from the staged area.

Comment: @Gn13l: Yes, the prompt hints at this: `Unstage this hunk [y,n,q,a,d,/,e,?]? `.

Comment: Ooooohhhh!! This made me happy. I hadn't thought of a patch mode for reset! That's so neat!